# vertical centering using "table-cell" within bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to vertically and horizontally center a div using the "table-cell" method because is not requiring a specific height, but unfortunately is not working without specifying a height.

Why is not working ?

I have this markup:

```
<section class="content-01 v-center">
<div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="slogan text-center">
      <h1>VERTICAL CENTERING</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.content-01.v-center {
display: table;
width: 100%;

}

.content-01.v-center>div {
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
float: none;
}
```

And here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ntK2/)

Any ideas what am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The code works if you set a height to `<section>`

Comment: it's centered http://jsfiddle.net/2ntK2/1/ and even if you set height to section works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `html` and `body` tags end before the bottom of the viewport:

[image: End of HTML element]

At the very least you would have to tell the browser that the height of the `html` and `body` elements is at least 100%:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

As well as specifying a height for the container `section`:

```
.content-01.v-center {
    /* ... */
    height: 100%;  
}
```

[image]

Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ntK2/3/